# Implement ASP.NET Core Web API with JWT and callback url

Tags: .net-core, callback, jwt

I have the following scenario for API integration Guide:

As its goal is the process of verifying the user who logs into the system using his ID number, after which the system will send the ID number that was entered using the API to another external system, and then that external system will send a random number to a special application on the mobile phone. This number will be shown on the login page.
Through the mobile application, the user selects the desired number from three numbers shown in the mobile application, as only one of them is the correct number.
The external system then sends the user data to the call-back page.

Which we have two parts:
The first part needs to be implemented to complete the authorization request flow. This flow initiates a new request within the mobile app for the targeted User.

The sample request body is like this:

```
{ 
    "id": "1000062537", 
    "action": "SpRequest", 
    "service": "Login" 
}
```

The sample response is like this:

```
{ 
    "transId": "3136fd60-3f89-4d24-a92f-b9c63a53807f", 
    "random": "38" 
}
```

- `transId`: a transaction ID, it's a unique identifying number.
- `random`: the number should be displayed to the user so he can click on the mobile app.

The second part that needs to be implemented to complete the mobile app authorization request flow.

The client must provide a destination URL (callback URL) that should be published on the internet using a fully qualified domain name (FQDN) where the response will be posted.

Callback URL:   https://example.net/iam-callback

For sample response body: we will send an acknowledgment response to the client on two cases:

- COMPLETED: successful transaction (within the time frame and correct random)
- REJECTED: The user rejects the transaction.

A sample "completed" body looks like this:

```
{ 
    "response": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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_ZitipIiwiZW5OYXRpb25hbGl0eSI6IlNhdWRpIEFyYWJpYSIsImRvYkciOiIxOTc5LTAwLTI3IiwiZG9iSCI6MTM5OTA3MDEsImFyQ2FyZElzc3VlUGxhY2UiOiLYp9it2YjYp9mEINin2YTYsdmK2KfYtiIsImVuQ2FyZElzc3VlUGxhY2UiOiJQZXJzb25hbCBTdGF0dXMgQWRtaW5pc3RyYXRpb24sIFJpeWFkaCJ9LCJhdWQiOiJUQ0NfU1BfVEVTVCIsImV4cCI6MTY3MzQyNzk2NiwiaXNzIjoiTmFmYXRoIEFwcCBUZXN0IiwiaWF0IjoxNjczNDI3MzY2LCJuYmYiOjE2NzM0MjczNjZ9.JvwBxO2ynUv1OXqp-4m8-RCDeu9C2MsWKs5EskqLcq9xfv0hBzlsW5bTo7-aRG6VWpv04odYDp_OS6sS8iAf5rY4mq5zQtYs4Pksee47k_1guTqRw8_7tJKOGh_TTWSsmP_4KvkOsuH2fhRevVASIAw0xLRdOBazSMf4H-b-ddyPSeGL3bcDIcjq5qlXw9tHBVyzIxj-_XYhBNgkWJBXxkySEwtxfgUZ4J_UcYIWWQKeaqzDPPMjcj510a4ZBv5ulAX7ig0ez9U7ABMFytyI_vaHnqte9n615lP418_br-TNyWYxB88qcjdGhaPT1ijnUhzjJfP_s2pIT43aKFPplg", 
    "status":"COMPLETED", 
    "transId":"b1d64420-9fa9-475e-ad13-864cba704078", 
    "serviceName":"Login" 
}
```

Which completed response elements like:

```
response { "userInfo":{ "id":1000000446, "idVersion":1, "NameFirst":"Mark", "NameFather":"Sari","gender":"M", 
"IdIssueDateG":"2015-00-16", "IdIssueDateH":14360728, "idExpiryDateG":"2034-00-10", "idExpiryDateH":14560728, "nationality":113}, 
"aud":"TCC_SP_TEST", 
"exp":1671726627, 
"iss":"App Test", 
"iat":1671726027, 
"nbf":1671726027}
```

How I can implement this API Guide using my project which is created by Visual Studio with ASP.NET Core?